# access event click of button inside of kendo window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a command button from a kendo grid that launches a kendo window.  Inside of the kendo window I have a button that I want to post to a controller, with data back from other objects in the kendo window.  I have searched and found people who have done it, but no actual full example code.  The button is in my kendo window, it's not one of the 'action' buttons on the top of the window.  Thanks!

cshtml:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("SMSwindow")
            .Title("Send SMS")
            .Visible(false)
            .Modal(true)
            .Draggable(true)
            .Width(600)               
        )
```

javascript:

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
<div id="sms-container" style="background-color: \\#f0f0f0; padding-left:10px">
    <h3>#= GroupName #<h3>
    <div>
        <input id="txtsub" style="font-size:12px" type="text" value="#= Subject #" />
    <div>
    <div style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px">
        <textarea id="txtbody" rows="10" cols="20" style="font-size:12px;" wrap="hard">#= Body #</textarea>
    <div>
    <div style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px">
        <input id="btnsend" style="font-size:14px" value="Send" type="submit" size="5" formmethod="post" />
    <div>
</div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var smsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

function SendSMS(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var wnd = $("#SMSwindow").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.content(smsTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
$(document).on('click', 'SelectorForYourButton', function() {
    //Handle your event here.
});
```

Comment: I've already tried something similar with '$("#SMSwindow").data().kendoWindow.bind('refresh', function (e) { $("#btnsend").click(function() { alert($("#txtsubject").value());}); }); Which didn't work at all either?  When I click the button, I don't get anything?

Comment: Yes, I did try it and placed an alert().  It never fired?

Comment: After reading some of the other posts and answers to kendo templates on here, especially OnaBai, I was finally able to figure this out. I had to insert the code after passing the dataItem. NumoCarmo was correct, or at least pointed me in the right direction. I just had to figure out where to insert the statements, allowing to add other functions using kendowindo.element as well. Thanks OnaBai!